# PHP multidimensional array elements being skipped

Tags: php, arrays

I have set up a multidimensional array in PHP like this:

```
$contents = array(
    "Header1" => array(
         "Section 1" => array (
               "Description1",
               "Notes1",
         ),
         "Gap" => "Gap",
         "Section 2" => array (
               "Description2",
               "Notes2",
         ),
         "Gap" => "Gap",
         "Section 3" => array (
               "Description3",
               "Notes3",
         ),
    ),
);
```

then I loop through this array as follows:

```
foreach ($contents as $header => $section) {
      foreach ($section as $title => $details) {
            echo $title."<br>";
      }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Section1
Gap
Section2
Section3
```

Why isn't the second "Gap" showing?

Thanx

Comment: That's why: http://codepad.org/zvuYLP6P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can't have duplicate array keys. The second one overwrites the first.

Use `Gap2` or something for your next array key. Or, better yet, nest it:

```
array(
    'Gap' => array(
        'Gap1',
        'Gap2'
    )
);
```

Comment: The first one overwrites the second one :)

Comment: @Akam Hash-maps (also known as associative arrays in PHP) don't guarantee order. See this http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k04-p2i. The second value takes precedence, whether or not it shows up in the place of the first. Curious why you posted a code sample after I clearly posted one that indicated you weren't going to win this ;).

Comment: we are not competitor to win or loss. it's a matter to learn, correct and incorrect :)

Comment: Ok thanks, this is indeed a very stupid mistake :). Well, I won't make it again, that's what matters...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two values in your array bind to the same key. A common method is to put your multiple values inside another sub-array, but while using the same key. It adds complexity to your code though. Careful.